# WiFi password is correct but it is telling me it is wrong

Tags: wifi

I know my WiFi password is correct, but just today it is telling me on my iPad it is wrong.  How can I get it to work.

Comment: I've seen this before but the trouble has to do with "neighbors" having the same make router and using the default router SSID (the same SSID.)  Do you have a unique SSID for your network?  Did you try "forgetting" the network and re-joining?

Answer (score 1):

Try these in order:

1. Ensure Wi-Fi is turned on
2. Ensure your iPad can see the Wi-Fi network (SSID) you're attempting to connect to
3. Reboot your iPad & re-try
4. Settings > General > Reset > Reset Network Settings. This also resets Wi-Fi networks and passwords, cellular settings & any VPNs that you’ve previously configured.